# double or triple seasonality ARIMA modelling in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to find whether there is any package in R that deals with multiple seasonality for ARIMA models and, if not, if there is any way of going through it.

I have an hourly series and would like to test seasonality for `lags=c(24,7*24,30*24)`

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `forecast` package , function `dshw` which Returns forecasts using Taylor's (2003) Double-Seasonal Holt-Winters method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TBATS model](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/forecast/docs/tbats), and [her's](http://www.r-bloggers.com/seasonal-periods/) an example

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post the relevant parts of the link too in case the link breaks in the future.